# Is there a Web app for building GeoExt tree configurations?

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, wfs, json, geoext

I have a GeoExt [application](http://map.rostmuseum.ru) and looking for approaches for building tree configuration (in JSON format). Now tree configuration is made manually and looks like:

```
    var treeConfig = new OpenLayers.Format.JSON().write([
    {
        text: "Layers",
        expanded: true,
        icon: "./images/Layers.png",
        children: [
            {
                text: "Nature",
                icon: "./images/globe.png",
                checked: false,
                group: true,
                children: [{
                    nodeType: "gx_layer",
                    layer: "Lakes",
                    icon: "./images/lake.png"
                },
                {
                    nodeType: "gx_layer",
                    layer: "Bogs",
                    icon: "./images/bog.png"
                }]
            }
            ...
```

But I would like to have web-application which I can use for building such configuration. All layers are published as WFS layers and it is possible to get the list of layers using GetCapabilities request, [for example](http://map.rostmuseum.ru/wfsstore.html). Please give me any advice or may be known approaches how I can solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also the LayerTreeBuilder ux. Check out the sources from http://svn.geoext.org/sandbox/mapgears/geoext.ux/ux/LayerTreeBuilder/ and see an example here: http://dev.geoext.org/sandbox/mapgears/geoext.ux/ux/LayerTreeBuilder/examples/tree-builder.html

Answer (score 0):

**GeoEXT has this example: wms-tree**

(which can easily be modifed for WFS rather than WMS)

*This example shows how to use GeoExt.tree.WMSCapabilitiesLoader to populate a tree with the hierarchical structure of a WMS GetCapabilities response. The example also shows how to customize the loader's createNode method to add a checkbox with a checkchange listener that adds and removes layers to and from the map.*

http://api.geoext.org/1.0/examples/wms-tree.html

But you will have to customise this yourself - there is no 'WebApp' to do this currently.